# How can I tell if a Mercurial command has been passed an option via an external hook?

Tags: mercurial

Ideally I'd like an answer to the title question.

However, for my particular case, I have a Perl script that I want to run from the `precommit` hook and I'd like to know if Mercurial was invoked with the `-A` option passed to the `commit` command (e.g. `hg commit -A`) and if it wasn't, is it possible to "pass" it in at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to seem a little silly, but in addition to the `precommit` hook, there's a pre-XXXX (and post-XXXX) hook for every command, which gets some different variables:

> `pre-<command>`
>
> Run before executing the associated
>   command. The contents of the command
>   line are passed as $HG_ARGS. Parsed
>   command line arguments are passed as
>   $HG_PATS and $HG_OPTS. These contain
>   string representations of the data
>   internally passed to .
>   $HG_OPTS is a dictionary of options
>   (with unspecified options set to their
>   defaults). $HG_PATS is a list of
>   arguments. If the hook returns
>   failure, the command doesn't execute
>   and Mercurial returns the failure
>   code.

So do a `pre-commit` hook instead and check those variables.